# How / where can we post meetings of interest to this community?

Tags: discussion

As this 'open data' community starts building, there are going to be a number of meetings that would be appropriate to advertise.

For instance, the May 16-17th meeting at the National Academies that's open to the public (although the registration deadline was a few days ago):

- [Public Access to Federally-Supported Research and Development Data and Publications: Two Planning Meetings](http://sites.nationalacademies.org/DBASSE/CurrentProjects/DBASSE_082378#.UY85q44f6tc)

Or the session proposals for the Fall AGU go through.  (sorry, can't direct link because the ScholarOne abstract system that they use just plain sucks)**

... I'm debating if it's worth listing the invitation-only meetings, such as the 
OSTP Big Data Senior Steering Group meeting at the end of the month.  (maybe so people know to look for reports after the fact?  have to balance that against people bugging the organizers to try to get an invitation ... like I managed to pull off for [BRDI](http://sites.nationalacademies.org/PGA/brdi/index.htm)'s meeting on [Data Attribution & Citation](http://sites.nationalacademies.org/PGA/brdi/PGA_080121).)

** Disclaimer : I'm the submitter of the two proposals, one invitation-only Union, one open in Public Affairs; and I'm also the person who was circulating the petition to free the AGU session data at the 2011 meeting, so I have a recorded bias against ScholarOne (in part because I can share a direct link to a session I propose, so people can easily submit to it!)

Answer (score 4):

Would it be appropriate then to have a resource question "Where can I find out about meetings on open data?" that provided links to other sources that do allow that type of ephemeral material?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more sensible this answer seems to me. These other sources are also the places where the existence of this site ought to be declared (once the beta becomes public).

Answer (score 3):

You can't, by design. Stack Exchange is not a forum. Forums are largely discussion-based and tend to follow less strict rules about what posts can be like.

**On Stack Exchange, we require every new thread to be started with a question and every response to that question to be an attempt at answering it.**

You might post a question asking "Where should I post events about Open Data for (*geographical area)?" and get your answer.

Comment: You can ... because I've been abusing the wiki aspect for [Translating cooking terms between US / UK / AU / CA / NZ](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/67) on Cooking.SE, and it's currently the 7th highest ranked "question" on the site.  There's a difference between social convention and truly not being able to.  As for the '... for Geographical Area?' bit ... I'll happily vote to close it for being too localized.

Comment: @Joe, the social convention we are trying to enforce is that this is a Q&A community, not a forum.

Comment: and while this community is still young and not getting over-run by idiots, you can make informed, selective decisions about individual items that may not be a "question" or have a single definitive "answer" but still are of value to the community can be made to fit within the technical limitations of the SE framework.  One or two questions that are used as a wiki does not make this whole site a 'forum'.  Hell, if they want to get away from the 'forum', then there also needs to be a crackdown on comments on just about every SE site I'm a member of.

Answer (score 2):

The majority of my visits to the 101 SE sites resulted from a search-engine link. Questions and answers, problems and resolutions, quandaries and tools to address them -- these hold up over time, whereas an alert to a meeting coming up has a considerably shorter shelf life.

I agree that this community would probably like such announcements. But places exist already for disseminating that kind of information. This doesn't have to be an "All Things Open Data" site, just as a dictionary (useful as it is) doesn't try to also be a thesaurus (useful as it is).